# JTable without a header

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Can anyone tell me how to create a table without a table header?

I am making Sudoku puzzle and I want to create a table without the table header in Java. Is it possible?

Comment: Don't add column names ... use any other constructor ...  or default?
I hope you are talking about JTable..

Comment: @saurabh: 3133t speak is not welcome here.  I fixed your post but next time refrain from using "any1", "plz thx" and several "??".  Can i haz cheezburger?

Comment: what table? does it need chairs too? lol

Comment: @SyntaxT3rr0r is 3133t name though ;)

Answer (score 38):

I don't think that you want your Sudoku to scroll, so the easiest way should be **not** to put your table into a [`JScrollPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html), which is responsible for displaying the header:

[image]

---

The other way is to call

```
table.setTableHeader(null);
```

Comment: For me, neither solution has any effect on the header.  I've even tried `table.getTableHeader.setVisible(false)` but I still have a blank grey spot where the header would be.  I know this is an old post; has the API changed, or am I missing something?

Comment: Looks like you are missing something, I just tried both suggested ways and they work. Setting the TableHeader invisible indeed leaves a grey spot since the layout does not change. If you cannot solve it, feel free to ask another question with a short example to reproduce your problem and a screenshot of the result.

Answer (score 8):

Anyone having problems with the suggested methods, try the following:

```
jTable.getTableHeader().setUI(null);
```

This is tested with Java 8.

Answer (score 3):

So the trick seems to be to first set a header using the DefaultTableModel constructor but then later to call setTableHeader(null);

[image]

Here is some demo code:

```
package net.raysforge.visual.demo;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
public class JTableAndGBC {

    private String[] columnNames = {"Source", "Hit", "Last", "Ur_Diff"};
    private JTable table;
    private Object[][] data = {{"Swing Timer", 2.99, 5, 1.01},
        {"Swing Worker", 7.10, 5, 1.010}, {"TableModelListener", 25.05, 5, 1.01}};
    private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);

    public JTableAndGBC() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        table = new JTable(model);
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        table.setTableHeader(null);
        panel.add(pane, gbc);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new JTableAndGBC();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Dummies like me: do this :]

```
jTable.setTableHeader(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Try These Steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CODTl.png):

> JtableProperties > TableHeader > CustomCode > Null

Answer (score 0):

jTable.getTableHeader().setUI(null) will not work after (if) L&F is changed.

What worked for me was to reset the visibility for the column headers of the scrollpane (in my cases assigned to variable scrollPaneSummary) that wraps the JTable this way:

```
scrollPaneSummary = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
scrollPaneSummary.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(javax.swing.JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
scrollPaneSummary.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(javax.swing.JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
scrollPaneSummary.setViewportView(  summaryJtable  );
scrollPaneSummary.setColumnHeaderView( summaryJtable.getTableHeader());

// make JTable headers invisible
scrollPaneSummary.getColumnHeader().setVisible(false);
scrollPaneSummary.revalidate();
```